# Matlab: Solving equation with different input variables

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

The equation I want to solve is

```
syms w v;
rho_air = 1.25;
equ = w == 0.5 * rho_air * v^2
```

The problem is that sometimes, I want to solve w from v, an sometimes from v to w.

How can I do it?

I only know to do it like this(This is now not working, and I don't know why):

```
syms v;
rho_air = 1.25;
w = 1;
equ = w == 0.5 * rho_air * v^2;
```

But then I have to change it to solve v, like

```
syms w;
rho_air = 1.25;
v = 1;
equ = w == 0.5 * rho_air * v^2;
```

which is quite repetative. Is there anyway to solve it more elegantly?

Comment: so @cqcn1991 did any answer provided help you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In old Matlab versions you need to define the equation as  a string; then you can  apply [`solve`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html):

```
>> syms w v;
rho_air = 1.25;
>> equ = 'w = 0.5 * rho_air * v^2';

>> solve(equ, w)
ans =
0.5*rho_air*v^2

>> solve(equ, v)
ans =
  (2^(1/2)*w^(1/2))/rho_air^(1/2)
 -(2^(1/2)*w^(1/2))/rho_air^(1/2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using a function, in which the inputs are the variable to solve for (as a string) and rho_air. It's quite self-explanatory. And I don't know why your above code does not work; you are just missing the call to solve and you're good to go :)

```
function [ out ] = SolveFor(Var2Solve,rho_air)

if strcmp(Var2Solve,'v')

    syms Var2Solve
    v = Var2Solve

    w = 1;
    equ = w == 0.5 * rho_air * v^2;
    out = solve(equ,v)

elseif strcmp(Var2Solve,'w')

    syms Var2Solve
    w = Var2Solve

    v = 1;
    equ = w == 0.5 * rho_air * v^2;
    out = solve(equ,w)

end


end
```

TESTS (in command window):

```
SolveSym('v',1.25)

out =

  (2*10^(1/2))/5
 -(2*10^(1/2))/5
```

and

```
SolveSym('w',1.25)

out =

5/8
```